# G-Suite - Upload data to the same Google Drive from Multiple User Accounts - Error 403 User rate limit exceeded

Tags: google-drive-api

So forgive me if this is a silly question but i am having problems using multiple accounts and uploading data to the same google drive

Setup

Google Drive being used below to User01

Linux:

rclone remote setup to connect to Google Drive with api credentials and encrypted along the way. ** THIS WORKS AS IT SHOULD

Setup another user on my G-Suite (User02) and create a new remote using the api credentials for User02 but the connection token for User01. I believe this is the method to firstly use User02 upload quota (specifying cred key and secret) then uploading data to google drive using token from User02

Firstly is my assumption correct?

When i do the above and attempt to copy data to google drive i get error 403 user rate exceeded. I have checked the quotas and they are no way being reached so i am at a loss as to what is going on.

Anyone done this before and got it working?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the token of *User01* then you are actually using your app as the *User01*.

I think that for your case you shouldn't be using [Domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) to impersonate the *User02* or whoever you want in your domain.

Your quota could be to try to upload files too big, or too many request to the server. Maybe post more information/source code/message error to try to debug it.

Comment: So I have checked quotas on both user account whilst I see the error and they are in no way being hit.

As for the code, I have wiped rclone config from my test rig so that I don't have to pay for additional g-suite users when I am not using them.

Comment: I just assumed that if I create a remote for user01 which is connected using the cred ID & Key from that users dev console which is then connected to its own google drive, I would then be able to create a new user, new remote with the new users cred ID & key from the dev console which I then authenticate using the email/password of the first user giving the 2nd user the same level of access to user1 google drive and add files to the same drive together utilising upload quotas from both.

This doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: If I create separate remotes for each and then point them to their own google drive this works however you then have to work at migrating user2 files onto user2 google drive in order to manage them in one place which is messy

Comment: What are you meaning by remotes? Could you maybe share the code you are using to make the request? What is your G-Suite subscription.

Comment: Rclone config below

`[gd-crypt-01]
type = crypt
remote = gd-User01:/Folder
filename_encryption = standard
directory_name_encryption = true
password = -******
password2 = ******`

`[gd-crypt-02]
type = crypt
remote = gd-User02:/Folder
filename_encryption = standard
directory_name_encryption = true
password = *****
password2 = ****`

`[gd-user01]
type = drive
client_id = *****
client_secret = *****
scope = drive
token = {"access_token":"******","token_type":"Bearer","refresh_token":"*****"}
root_folder_id = ******`

Comment: `gd-user02]
type = drive
client_id = ******
client_secret = *****
scope = drive
token = {"access_token":"****","token_type":"Bearer","refresh_token":"*****"}
root_folder_id = ****`

`FROM=“/localfolder/“
TO=“gd-crypt-01:/“
rclone copy $FROM $TO -c --no-traverse --transfers=300 --checkers=300 -P -vv`

`FROM=“/localfolder/“
TO=“gd-crypt-02:/“
rclone copy $FROM $TO -c --no-traverse --transfers=300 --checkers=300 -P -vv`

Comment: As mentioned before, when creating the gd-user remotes, at the point where you need to authenticate with google i used the login details for the main drive i wish to dump all the files onto which belongs to User01.

I have an unlimited g-suite account

Comment: Maybe is this a problem from the rclone side, could you check doing normal request to the Drive API?